# Removing non-unique data on insert

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

Table entity column is unique, and I'm trying to add items. Items amount is fairly big, so i'm trying to avoid connecting to a database many times. What is the best way to ignore duplicates?

Example: [code](http://pastebin.com/90xFeWs2)

Edit: Problem was word1 was of type nchar(50), so after changing it to nvarchar(50) everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to avoid inserting those words that are already in the table.

```
HashSet<string> words; 

List<string> newWords = words.Except(lh.words.Select(w=>w.word1))
                             .ToList();

lh.words.InsertAllOnSubmit(newWords.Select(x=> new word { word1 = x}));
```

Your code, as you have it today, will send all the `INSERTS` one after each other, in the same batch. It'll create a single connection for them all with the one `SubmitChanges()` that you have.

Comment: have you considered perormnce of hashset for a large no of records?

Comment: Problem is that Hashset will contain elements, already in db. And elements in HashSet are lowercased already.